# How is the sweep of duty cycle handled in common microcontrollers?

Tags: arduino, pwm, pic

I have designed a PWM module in Verilog, and it was giving me a glitch. After debugging it for some time, I found that the value of the duty cycle was changing twice within a certain period.

How do microcontrollers such as Arduino or PIC ensure that the duty cycle is not changed twice within a certain period? Are they controlling it in hardware or software? if they are controlling in hardware how they ensure that some duty cycles are not missed when they enable the prescalar.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any standard way, but it seems common that the duty cycle register is only read at the end of each period. So if the program writes to it multiple times, it won't matter. This will be controlled by hardware in the PWM hardware peripheral.

Comment: So, this implies that it is handled in hardware. I had assumed that it was managed in software through two methods:

1.Polling the counter register, updating the duty cycle when it resets to zero.
2. Generating an interrupt at the end of each period.

Comment: The whole purpose of using a PWM hardware peripheral is that you should just be able to update a duty cycle register and then be on your merry way, without any fuss. Otherwise if implementing PWM manually in software with timers and GPIO, glitches may appear in the PWM. It can be done, but that's painful and requires some serious real-time programming considerations. For example you can never have a duty cycle shorter than your interrupt latency + ISR execution overhead. That's inconvenient.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Adam01 I have done it both ways: hardware and software. Some processors (by no means all) have invariant cycle-accurate delays into interrupt code (ADSP-21xx comes to mind) so you have no jitter at all if you are carefully coding in assembly. But with software interrupts there is still a delay and handling sweeps that can go from 0% to 100% with precision does take some rigorous care in design. As Lundin suggests, modern MCUs sport very flexible timer modes and that's the best way to go if one of them is PWM or can be manipulated into providing PWM, indirectly.

Comment: @Adam01 You ask about sweeping and I think that would require a more careful and crafted answer to you, whether by software or by hardware peripheral -- those are usually easily configured for a fixed value. But automatically adjusting the PWM to make a sweep isn't something I've yet seen in a hardware peripheral. Instead, they require software baby-sitting for something like that. But I have limited experiences, too. So I may have simply missed-out. (And I haven't needed to make an all-hardware/FPGA sweeping PWM before, either.)

Answer (score 2):

> How do microcontrollers such as Arduino or PIC ensure that the duty cycle is not changed twice within a certain period?

They don't. As Justme said,

- Either the PWM unit is dumb and you write to the compare register directly, so if you write a value that is lower than the current value, and at the same time the counter crosses that value, then the comparison is missed
- Or the PWM unit is smart and you write the compare value into a separate register, which is then loaded into the actual compare register when the counter wraps around, ensuring no comparison event is ever missed.

> I have designed a PWM module in Verilog, and it was giving me a glitch. After debugging it for some time, I found that the value of the duty cycle was changing twice within a certain period.

But "How do microcontrollers do it" is not the real question. I guess the real question is how to get rid of your glitch.

The answer is to synchronize the unit that is generating the compare values with the PWM counter wrap around event.

So. Suppose you have a counter which increments on every clock. Then either it wraps around naturally as it runs out of bits, which limits you to frequencies that are a power of two divisor of your clock... or you add a separate comparator with a "period" register to reset your counter when needed, which gives you flexible period.

In the first case, wraparound is the carry generated when incrementing the counter, and in the second case, it is the output of the period comparator. Anyway, you have a signal which is activated for one clock cycle, in the cycle when the counter is reset to zero, let's call this "wraparound event".

```
assign wraparound = (counter == period);
always( @posedge clock ) begin
    output  <= counter < dutycycle; 
    counter <= wraparound ? 0 : (counter+1);
end
```

The duty cycle should be changed on wraparound to avoid missing compares. In a MCU you'd do that by setting an interrupt on counter wraparound, and updating the duty cycle in this interrupt. Thus it is only updated once per period. Note this sets the duty cycle for the next period, because by the time the interrupt code gets executed, the counter has wrapped around and started counting. It is only really usable if the PWM unit belongs to the "smart" category where you can change duty cycle on the fly. In verilog you would keep the same philosophy: generate and update the duty cycle once per period. The interrupt is replaced by your wraparound signal.

```
always( @posedge clock ) begin
    if( wraparound ) dutycycle <= next_dutycycle_value;
end
```

If you can generate the next PWM duty cycle value in less than 1 clock cycle, for example by a simple counter which makes a ramp, then you can put that code in the above. If it is more complicated then you need to compute the value ahead of time and have it ready in a register, to be loaded when needed. In both cases, once per PWM period.

Note PWM is sampled, at a sample rate of one per period. This means there is one duty cycle value per period. Attempting to cram more duty cycle values into a period is like attempting to cram more samples into one sample, it won't work.

---

Now you're talking about a prescaler and different clock for the counter. Besides clock domain crossing headaches, FPGAs's internals are more suited to having one clock and clock enables:

```
always( @posedge clock ) begin
    if( reset ) begin 
        counter <= 0;
    end else if( increment ) begin
        counter <= (counter<max_value) ? (counter+1) : 0;
    end
```

So the counter is clocked by the same clock as the rest of the circuit, which is much simpler for FPGA internal routing. It only increments if signal "increment" is asserted, which in this case is your [clock enable](https://www.fpga4student.com/2017/08/how-to-generate-clock-enable-signal.html) signal. The synthesis tool will implement the adder and comparator to generate the next counter value, route the result of this to a register and loop the output back. And it will simply use "increment" as a clock enable for the register, so the next counter value is only taken when "increment" is asserted.

So all you need is for your prescaler to generate a 1-clock cycle long pulse every time the counter should be incremented.

Note: Typically the role of a prescaler is to save silicon by using a smaller counter and comparator, so they're usually implemented as "divide by \$ 2^n \$". In this case you'd use a bunch of flops to make a divide-by-\$ 2^N \$ then a mux to select which output 0<=n<=N to take, which outputs a square wave at the divided frequency. To get the one clock pulse mentioned above, you can use a simple edge detector like "previous_value==0 && current_value==1".

If you don't need to save area, you can also just use more bits in the counter and get rid of the prescaler.

Comment: what will happen when we will be using a prescalar, some of the dutycycle values will be missed in this case.

Comment: It depends, with a prescaler the counter will just count slower. If you still generate and update the duty cycle when the counter wraps around, it won't miss cycles, the only difference will be lower frequency and resolution.

Comment: In this scenario, my "dutycycle_temp" register is updated on the Wishbone clock, which operates at a faster frequency, while my counter operates on a slower clock that is prescaled. I presume that in this situation, some of the duty cycles might be missed, even if I update the duty cycle register with the "dutycycle_temp" register when the counter wraps around.

Comment: Why would they be missed if you update once per counter period? You're using gated clock for the counter, right? When in doubt post some code.

Comment: I'm using a C code for testing. The C code sweeps the duty cycle value from 1 to 255. In RTL, it will be written to the dutycycle_temp register (which operates on a faster clock), while the counter, running on a slower clock, will receive the updated duty cycle value to be checked when it wraps around. Now, there's a chance that by the end of, let's say, one period, the dutycycle_temp will be written multiple times, and we will only get the latest value while the rest will be missed. I am actually talking about the control of DC value from C code to dutycycle_temp.

Comment: The counter should be using clock enable, so everything runs on the same clock: counter, bus, your whole peripheral. Much simpler and avoids issues with clock domain crossing. If your C code writes several different values of duty cycle per period, then fix the code so it only does it once.

Comment: How can it be ensured in C code that only one duty cycle per period is sent? I suppose one approach could be to generate an interrupt from the peripheral when the counter wraps around. Based on this value, the c code can then send the next duty cycle value.

Comment: If I were to use the prescaled clock for the entire peripheral, wouldn't it slow down the processor? That's why I opted to use the slower clock only for the counter.

Comment: No the whole peripheral should run at the bus clock, including the counter and prescaler. Then use a clock enable generated by the prescaler to increment the counter only on cycles where it should. Yes you should use an interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Take a short look into the datasheet from the [ATMEGA328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), the controller from the arduino uno:

[image: ATMEGA328P datasheet Timer]

It describes on page 131 the timer register where the counter and compare values are stored. Note that ist says "Modifying the counter
(TCNT2) while the counter is running, introduces a risk of missing a compare match", which shows your issue.

Looking  two pages further in the registers there are asynchronous status registers:[image: ATMEGA328P datasheet status registers]

This implies a way for the control unit to update the count from an temporary status register without causing any glitches.

I assume that other microcontrollers have a similiar architecture on the timer registers.

Comment: This is a timer peripheral though, not a dedicated PWM peripheral. Sometimes they are one and the same. Sometimes there is only a timer peripheral. And using timer peripherals to achieve PWM might be clunky and painful. Therefore we pick a suitable MCU for the project - if we need PWM, we look for a MCU with a sensible PWM peripheral. Real embedded projects don't start with picking an archaic 8-bitter MCU and then try to shoe-horn the project requirements into the old MCU. Been there, done that - it is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one method.

It depends on the microcontroller.

In some MCUs you write to the compare register that the counter directly uses. Therefore it means that it is possible for the MCU to write a new value that is earlier than the current counter value and the event will be missed for one cycle.

In some MCUs you write to the compare register which gets latched into internal use at the start of a new period, so the compare event will not be missed. But what you write cannot affect the current cycle, but the next one.

So, whatever software you write, you have to take the hardware operation into account.

For example, if you get an interrupt on each overflow, the counter will advance already many counts before MCU software can load a new value for very short pulse. Which is why the latched load affecting the next cycle will work, but comes one cycle too late.